# Put a span tag in a data tag?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to add a span in a data- tag?

```
 <a href="#" data-content="<span>Vivamus </span>sagittis.">Printer 127.0.13.123</a>
```

The output show Vivamus sagittis rather than making the span tags

Comment: Just do it. Where's the problem?

If that doesn't work, use &gt; and &lt; instead.

<a href="#" data-content="&lt;span&gt;Vivamus &lt;/span&gt;sagittis.">Printer 127.0.13.123</a>

Comment: FWIW, the above code passes the w3.org validator. You set set it with jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function like so: `$('a').data('content', '<span>Vivamus </span>sagittis.');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: the popup shows this (<span>Vivamus </span>sagittis.) It shows the tag instead of making one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `data-html="true"`

```
<a href="#" data-html="true" data-content="<span>Vivamus </span>sagittis.">
  Printer 127.0.13.123</a>
```

Comment: the popup shows this (<span>Vivamus </span>sagittis.) It shows the tag instead of making one

Comment: @MattCharlton: what pop up? What's the control you're using?

Comment: @Matt Charlton: changed my answer. Please see if this helps.

Comment: Yes, that will do it - [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)